# SSH “Permission denied (publickey)” during reverse tunnel through AWS instance

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-tunneling, port-forwarding, amazon-ec2

I am trying to access a home desktop computer (A), from my laptop (C), through an EC2 instance (B). I have successfully set up many different kinds of tunnels and SSHed to my heart's content from (A) to (B), and back and forth between (B) and (C). I am *so close* to tunnelling straight from (A) to (C) but I keep getting the same error message.

So if: Me (A) ------> EC2 (B) ------> Target (C), I'm trying to tunnel straight from (A) to (C).

On the desktop (C), I run `ssh -N -R 52.60.xx.xx:1338:localhost:22 userB@machineB` and this seems to work fine, creating a tunnel and forwarding port 1338 on (B) back to itself (C).

Then on (A), I run `ssh -p 1338 userB@machineB -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -i ~/.ssh/keyToMachineC_rsa` and it seems to *almost* work.

With the `-v` flag I get a *lot* of output, but it seems to be connecting to the target machine (C) but then rejecting the key! The last several lines of the output look like this:

```
debug1: Host '[52.60.xx.xx]:1338' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/<Me>/.ssh/known_hosts:35
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/<Me>/.ssh/keyToMachineC_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/<Me>/.ssh/keyToMachineB_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

It looks like it's offering machine (C) the correct key but still being denied! I have manually place the correct matching public key in the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on machine (C)—in fact, I've created new key pairs several times and tried with different keys, always with this same result. The permissions on `~/.ssh` and `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on (C) are tightened down and they are all owned by the right user. I have all of the relevant settings that I could find in `sshd_config` completely open on (B) and (C), and in my AWS console.

Comment: You enabled "GatewayPorts yes" in the sshd?

Comment: @Ziazis yes, on the intermediate machine (B).